# Convert std::vector<complex<double>> to complex<double>[N] for FFT

Tags: c++, vector, fft

I'm working on an FFT-based wav file processing. I have developed/copied functions for wav read and fft processing.
The problem is that my wav read function returns a `vector`, and my FFT needs `complex<double>[N]`, and I can't figure out how to connect `vector<double>` or `vector<complex<double>>` to `complex<double>[N]`. How can I transform my data?
I'm sorry for my noobeness, it's my first question on SO.

```
void FFT(Complex f[], Complex ftilde[], int log2N);

vector<double> amplitudes;
WavReader("../Projects/Project4/input.wav", amplitudes);

size_t size = amplitudes.size();                        
const int new_size = resize(size);        // Finding nearest number power of 2
int log2N = log2(new_size);

using Complex = complex<double>;
amplitudes.resize(new_size);
std::vector<double> imag{ 0.0 };
imag.resize(new_size);
vector<complex<double>> cvec(amplitudes.size());

transform(amplitudes.begin(), amplitudes.end(), imag.begin(), cvec.begin(), [](double da, double db) 
{
    return complex<double>(da, db);
});
    
Complex f[N];                   // The input of FFT
```

Comment: what is the prototype of the functions you need to call that require `complex<double>[N]`?

Comment: void FFT(Complex f[], Complex ftilde[], int log2N);

Answer (score 0):

Use `FFT(cvec.data(), ???, log2N)`. The `data()` function will return a pointer to the start of the (contiguous) data of the vector. Just be sure that `log2N <= cvec.size()`.